# MS-DOS command-line set /p

Tags: command-line, dos, dosbox

I want to create a MS-DOS .bat program that asks user to select an option using the following line:

```
set /p opt=Select your option:
```

The line is executed, but it doesn't do anything and continues executing the rest of the batch file without user prompt. What is wrong? I tried this in DOSBox 0.74.

Comment: It works fine for me. Perhaps the version of DOS used in DOSBox doesn't support set /p? (Type `set /?` from the command line, and read the help it displays.)

Comment: @KenWhite `set /?` shows `Change environment variables.` and just `SET`, but the similar info is shown also for DIR although it has more working switches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DOSBox probably doesn't support setting environment variables through user prompt, so I downloaded working command.com from FreeDOS.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the documentation for SET by typing `set /?` or `help set` from a Windows command prompt, and you will see that the /P option is only available if extensions are enabled. The extensions are a part of Windows CMD.EXE, they are not available in the old DOS COMMAND.COM. In other words, the /P option is only available in Windows. It was not available in true DOS, so it makes sense that it will not work in DosBox either.

Answer (score 1):

you probably forgot a space after equals sign

```
set /p opt= Select your option:
```

P.S : use quotes around the string

Comment: There's no space needed around the equals sign for set /p. `set /p opt=Enter your choice:` works just fine.